# problems in finding mathematical reviews journal (MR XXX)

Tags: reference-request

for example, this one:

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0215729

the journal has the number like "MR215729 (35 #6564)"

I wanna know what does the 35 #6564 means...

because for some references, it just quote "MR 21 #852",

which i cannot find the MR number, which is "215729" like the previous one.

sounds weird enough to me :(

Comment: In 35 #6564, the 35 means volume 35 (which should be the year 1974, since MR started in 1940), and #6564 means it's review number 6564 of that volume.

Comment: The string "MR215729" refers to the item's classification in [*Current Mathematical Publications*](http://journalseek.net/cgi-bin/journalseek/journalsearch.cgi?field=issn&query=0361-4794). I don't know how widely circulated the print version has been in the past decade or so, but certainly in the 1970s and 1980s it was a common item in math department reading rooms/lounges, where current issues of math journals would sit for a few weeks before being shipped off to the library for more perminant storage.